# Comparing a paired count data

Tags: poisson-regression, count-data, paired-data

I have a group of patients who are subjected to treatment A. I wish to compare the number of events/patient before and after the treatment. The duration of follow up of before and after therapy is different since this is a retrospective study. How do I compare the number of episodes/patient before and after the treatment. my understanding is that I will have to use a poisson regression for the analysis.. is this correct?